# ViewModel with multiple table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, viewmodel

I'm a beginner and i want to do a viewmodel with controller for my application :

```
public class catalogue_produit
{
    [Key]
    public int PdtID { get; set; }

    public string PdtCode { get; set; }
    public string PdtNomCourt { get; set; }
    public string PdtNomLong { get; set; }
    public string PdtTexte { get; set; }
    public int PdtColisage { get; set; }
    public string PdtGencod { get; set; }
    public float PdtTva { get; set; }
    public float PdtTgap { get; set; }
    public string PdtRemplacerPar { get; set; }
    public bool PdtActif { get; set; }
    public bool PdtPau { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int FournisseurID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FournisseurID")]
        public virtual catalogue_fournisseur catalogue_fournisseur { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int FamilleID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FamilleID")]
        public virtual catalogue_famille catalogue_famille { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CategorieID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CategorieID")]
        public virtual catalogue_categorie catalogue_categorie { get; set; }
}

//Classe gérant les fiches techniques
public class catalogue_fichetechnique
{
    [Key]
    public int FtID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int PdtID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PdtID")]
        public virtual catalogue_produit catalogue_produit { get; set; }

    public string FtUrl { get; set; }
    public DateTime FtDate { get; set; }
}
```

So i do a viewmodel :

```
public class ProduitViewModel
{
    public catalogue_produit catalogue_produit { get; set; }
    public catalogue_fichetechnique catalogue_fichetechnique { get; set; }
}
```

And my Controller :

```
public class ProduitController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Produit/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ProduitViewModel product = new ProduitViewModel();
        return View(product);
    }
```

Error message on Index execution :

```
L'élément de modèle passé dans le dictionnaire est de type 'WEBPHSMVC.ViewModels.ProduitViewModel', mais ce dictionnaire requiert un élément de modèle de type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[WEBPHSMVC.ViewModels.ProduitViewModel]'. 
Description : Une exception non gérée s'est produite au moment de l'exécution de la requête Web actuelle. Contrôlez la trace de la pile pour plus d'informations sur l'erreur et son origine dans le code. 

Détails de l'exception: System.InvalidOperationException: L'élément de modèle passé dans le dictionnaire est de type 'WEBPHSMVC.ViewModels.ProduitViewModel', mais ce dictionnaire requiert un élément de modèle de type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[WEBPHSMVC.ViewModels.ProduitViewModel]'.

Erreur source: 




Une exception non gérée s'est produite lors de l'exécution de la requête Web actuelle. Les informations relatives à l'origine et l'emplacement de l'exception peuvent être identifiées en utilisant la trace de la pile d'exception ci-dessous.


Trace de la pile: 





[InvalidOperationException: L'élément de modèle passé dans le dictionnaire est de type 'WEBPHSMVC.ViewModels.ProduitViewModel', mais ce dictionnaire requiert un élément de modèle de type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[WEBPHSMVC.ViewModels.ProduitViewModel]'.]
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary`1.SetModel(Object value) +509563
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary..ctor(ViewDataDictionary dictionary) +371
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`1.SetViewData(ViewDataDictionary viewData) +48
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +99
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +115
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +295
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +23
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +242
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__1b() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +177
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +324
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +106
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +91
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +19
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +48
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9629296
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

But i'm not sure and my controller doesn't work :(
I want CRUD on my ProduitViewModel.

Please help me !

Comment: Please post your Controller code and describe what exactly doesn't work.

Comment: i add controller in original post. I can't generate an Index view :(

Comment: Can you post the error message you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

Your `ViewModel` contains the `catalogue_produit` model itself which is usually not what you want.

One of the main points of the `ViewModel` is that the `View` will be able to render itself without relying on `Models/Entities` that usually will not suit the `View` needs.

Answer (score 0):

Well, just read the error message would help :

You view has a model which is an `IEnumerable<ProduitViewModel>`, something like

```
@model IEnumerable<ProduitViewModel>
```

and you pass it a single instance of `ProduitViewModel`

So either change the model of the view to

```
@model ProduitViewModel
```

or send it an `IEnumerable`, not a single instance.